# Short story seemingly set in the past, but is really post-apocalyptic. People uncover US monuments (Staue of Liberty, Lincoln Memorial)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to track down a short story from my high school English class, but the details are fuzzy.

A group of people are exploring ancient ruins of a civilization and they're discussing how primitive they were.  In the end, you realize they are exploring a post apocalyptic U.S.  I think they found the Statue of Liberty or maybe the Lincoln Memorial?

Comment: Hi that's a good start. Please read https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337 and flesh out your question.

Comment: For instance, when did you read it? Were you in high school in 1960 or 2010? That will help us enormously.

Comment: So when they found the Statue of Liberty were they being pursued by gun-wielding apes on horseback?

Comment: Rings a bell. Could it have been they found the Jefferson Memorial and were trying to decipher the words carved there?

Answer (score 4):

"[Digging the Weans](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41485)" by Robert Nathan?  I can't find a free copy online but your description sounds very much like what I read in high school English class about 60 years ago.  You can read the story [here](https://harpers.org/archive/1956/11/digging-the-weans/) if you have a subscription to Harper's Magazine.

> THE inscription on the north wall of the
> temple at Pound-Laundry on the -east
> coast of the Great West Continent has finally
> been deciphered by the team led by Sf. B'Han
> Bollek. This work brings us certain assurance
> of the theory expressed by Bes Nef, Hanh Shui,
> and Nat Obelgerst-Levy that a people of considerable numbers and power formerly inhabited
> this salt and desolate land. It is a triumph for
> those archaeologists who have been working ever
> since the fortunate discovery of an ivory cross
> and string of beads at the northeast, or "Bosstin"
> tumulus, along with a rusted iron wheel which
> seems to have been designed to run along some
> kind of track or trolley. These artifacts, as every- .
> one knows, are now in the museum at Kenya.
> What we have been unable to discover, is the
> fate of these ancient people. That they perished
> in some sort of upheaval many thousands of
> years ago is clear from the inscription itself,
> which Sr. B'Han Bollek translates as follows:
> "nor [for north?] rain nor hail nor snow ... "
> there are some hieroglyphics missing, and the
> inscription ends with the phrase ... "their appointed rounds."

Comment: Who wrote this? How does it match the OP's description? See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) for some useful tips on how to write a good answer to a story id question.

Comment: Also a PDF at http://www.joshpachter.com/pages/weans.pdf

Comment: Maybe not clear in the quote but "Pound-Laundry" = "Washing Ton"

Comment: More details in [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/what-story-involves-archeologists-in-the-future-that-study-the-20th-century/48529#48529) answer.

Answer (score -1):

“By the Waters of Babylon” by Stephen Vincent Benét

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _By the Waters of Babylon_ matches the description given in the question. It'd help other users decide how likely it is to be the correct answer.